# Limit of $\frac{(2n-1)!! \sqrt{n}}{n! 2^n}$

Tags: limits

How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n-1)!! \sqrt{n}}{n! 2^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ ?

The expression can also be written as

$$ \sqrt{n} \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\cdot\cdot3\cdot1}{2n (2n-2) \cdot\cdot\cdot4\cdot2}=\sqrt{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2n-2}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: Wallis Product?

Comment: **Hint**. One may first write
$$\frac {1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} {2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)\cdot (2n+1)}=\frac {(2n)!} {4^n (n!)^2(2n+1)}$$ then one may use Stirling's formula:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$, it suffices to calculate 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{n}}{(2^nn!)^2}.
$$
This is now a straightforward application of Stirling's approximation